# A Trig Integral

Tags: definite-integrals, logarithms, closed-form

Does the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos(x) \, \ln\left( \frac{1 + a^{2} \sin(x)}{1 - a^{2} \sin(x)} \right) \, dx
\end{align}
have a closed form and what is changed if the limits are changed to $(- \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step I'd try is to use the properties of logarithms.

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}2\cos x[\ln(1+a^2\sin x)-\ln(1-a^2\sin x)]dx$$
$$u=a^2\sin x,du=a^2\cos xdx$$
$$\frac1{a^2}\int_0^{a^2}\ln(1+u)-\ln(1-u)du=$$
$$\frac1{a^2}\left[(1+u)\ln(1+u)-(1+u)+(1-u)\ln(1-u)-(1-u)\right]|_0^{a^2}=$$
$$\frac1{a^2}\left[(1+a^2)\ln(1+a^2)+(1-a^2)\ln(1-a^2)-2+2\right]=$$
$$\frac{(1+a^2)\ln(1+a^2)+(1-a^2)\ln(1-a^2)}{a^2}$$

If the lower limit is changed to $-\frac{\pi}2$, the result is $0$.  You are integrating an odd function.